# Как удалить кнопки Яндекс.Карт при помощи API?

Tags: html, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Создаю карту с меткой, все хорошо, создается без проблем. Но вот проблема, на карте куча ненужной информации, т.е. стандартные кнопки от Яндекс. Принтскрин прилагаю.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как создаю карту.

```
// Дождёмся загрузки API и готовности DOM.
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    // Создание экземпляра карты и его привязка к контейнеру с
    // заданным id ("map").

    var myMap;
    ymaps.geocode('<?echo $event['address']?>').then(function (res) {
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(),
            zoom : 16
        }),
        // Создаем геообъект с типом геометрии "Точка".
        myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({

        });

        var myGeocoder = ymaps.geocode("<?echo $event['address']?>");
        myGeocoder.then(
        function (res) {
            console.log(res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates());
            //myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
            myMap.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark(
            res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(), {
            hintContent: '<?echo $event['title']?>',
            balloonContent: '<?echo $event['title']?>'
        }, {
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            // Своё изображение иконки метки.
            //iconImageHref: 'default#shopIcon',
            // Размеры метки.
            //iconImageSize: [15, 26],
            // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
            // её "ножки" (точки привязки).

        }))
        }
        );
    });
}
```

Подскажите как убрать все лишние кнопки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы изменить набор контролов карты, добавьте свойство `control` во второй параметр. Например чтобы убрать все, укажите пустой массив при создании карты

```
...
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(),
        zoom : 16,
        controls: []
    }),
...
```

Также можете посмотреть [список](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.Manager-docpage/#add-param-control) контролов и их наборов, которые существуют по-умолчанию или можете добавить свой контрол.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли